# Chrome V8 errors

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I'm trying to build the Chrome V8 javascript engine so I can embed it into my c++ project. I'm following the tutorial [here](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP). I downloaded everything that was needed and managed to get the project solution created but when I compile it only 5 of the 12 solutions get compiled correctly. Can someone shed some light on my problem? There doesn't seem to be much info on the web about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tricks I learned are this:

use the correct `gyp` command that will generate correct sln files. maybe target architecture argument was wrong or some other parameter you supply to gyp.

I do not know how to properly "`clean`" the source tree, so if I wanted new options to gyp I just delete the whole source tree and unpack from original archive. (or use `svn`).

Make sure you use `python` and `cygwin` supplied with v8 sources.

I used pc emulator (`qemu`) to install Windows XP + Visual studio and v8 sources+tools.

I tried various versions of Visual Studio only VS Express 2010 worked.

On `linux` everything is simpler. And you do not even need to build it, just use "`aptitude install v8-dev`"

Comment: Some things are defiantly easier on linux haha, but I've already found out the problem. Thank you for sharing though, their doesn't seem to be to much good info on this subject.

Comment: @xDarkShadowx: What was your problem?